# What is hooks in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

What is hooks in Prestashop? How it works can anyone expalin it throw graphical representation.I am newbie in PS I do not know it works and and to pass variable inside it as well.Is there any trick to choose write hooks.

Comment: You should accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**In PrestaShop you have two kinds of hooks:**

1. `Display`-hooks: You can think of them as positions, where you can place design elements, for example from modules. Let's say you want to place a banner in the footer. Then "transplant" that module to the `displayFooter`, or choose a module that uses the wanted hook.
2. `Action`-hooks: You can think of them as timing for when you want an action to happen. Let's say you want to beg your customers to rethink if they delete an item from their cart, then add a popup or something at `actionObjectProductInCartDeleteAfter`, or choose a module that uses the wanted hook.

**How to use hooks in your module you say?**

Register the hook (most of the time done during install), like this:

```
public function install()
{
    return parent::install() 
    && $this->registerHook('displayFooter'); 
}
```

Then make an actual hook function:

```
public function hookDisplayFooter($params) {
    dump($params); // Gives an overview of some available params.  
    return 'Hello world';
}
```

Lastly hooks are executed in templates like this:

```
{hook h='displayFooter'}
```

You can also execute hooks from controllers like this:

```
Hook::exec($hook_name, $hook_args);
```

More info can be found in PrestaShop DevDocs:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/

Answer (score 0):

Hooks in PrestaShop deal with theme development. They are important for inserting modules into your theme. In PrestaShop official documentation you can find [list of basic hooks](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/).

To create your own hook go to the theme’s directory, for example, /themes/classic/, and select the necessary template in the templates/ folder. For instance, you can choose the site’s header template that is located at /themes/classic/templates/_partials/header.tpl. And with the help of the {hook h = ‘MyCustomNameHooks’} construction add hook to the header of the template: {hook h = ‘MySocialListHeader’}. The detailed information about hooks creating you can find [here](https://belvg.com/blog/creating-custom-hooks-in-prestashop-1-7.html).

If you want to know how to use custom hooks in PrestaShop 1.7, please, [read this](https://belvg.com/blog/custom-hooks-in-prestashop-1-7.html). We included video instruction there, so it will be easier to understand how to manage hooks.